# SQLite3 - Modify query to output a single row of total results

Tags: sqlite

The query below returns 100 results, each result with various counts. How would I modify my query to only return a single row with the total results count, i.e. 100?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Album Al, Track T
WHERE Al.AlbumId = T.AlbumId
GROUP BY T.AlbumId
HAVING COUNT(T.TrackId) > 10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may come a bit late, but the code below is the correct solution. It will count the total albums that have over 10 tracks (100 results) instead of each track in an album.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Album A
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(T.AlbumId) AS TrackCount
FROM Track T
WHERE A.AlbumId = T.AlbumId) > 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT * FROM Album Al, Track T
WHERE Al.AlbumId = T.AlbumId
GROUP BY T.AlbumId
HAVING COUNT(T.TrackId) > 10);
```

Or

```
SELECT COUNT(Album.AlbumId)
FROM Album Al, Track T
WHERE Al.AlbumId = T.AlbumId
GROUP BY T.AlbumId
HAVING COUNT(T.TrackId) > 10;
```

Not sure without having data to test with but i think the first one is what you're looking for.